# Can I export the default programs to use for different file types?

Tags: 16.04, mate, default-programs, file-format

I have changed a lot of defaults which programs should be used for which files, e.g. instead of using LibreOffice for CSV I use Sublime Text.

Is it possible to export those?

My System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, MATE

Comment: How did you change those defaults settings? Did you modify any file?

Comment: @M.Becerra With Caja: Right-click on the file of that type, Properties, Open With.

Answer (score 0):

The settings are stored in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and `/usr/share/applications/mate-mimeapps.list`. So you could just copy the contents of these files.

Comment: No, they are not stored there. The second file does not exist and the first does not contain `sublime_text` which is my default for many file types.

Comment: @MartinThoma I just corrected the second file. No idea if this answer is valid though

Comment: It certainly used to be `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` (I've posted as such myself elsewhere) but on my 16.04 system the relevant file now seems to be `~/.config/mimeapps.list`